# UILabel.attributedText.size return a optional(x, y), what does that stand for?

Tags: swift, uilabel, size

The UILabel.attributedText.size return a optional(x, y), what does that stand for?
For example Optional((3323.7421875, 20.671875))is the output, I was quite confused....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the size required to draw the string.
Probably its optional because you call this function on an optional label

for example,

```
var userNameLabel: UILabel!
let what = userNameLabel.attributedText!.size()
```

would return just Size

but

```
var userNameLabel: UILabel?
let what = userNameLabel?.attributedText!.size()
```

would return optional(size)

Comment: Your second example is wrong, does not compile. Have you tested it?

Comment: I missed a "?" after the userNameLabel, see edit for fix

Comment: @Roee84 Is the first one the width of the label, second one the height of the label?

Comment: yes, but notice you are asking about attributedText.
maybe you are really interested at  userNameLabel.frame.width and userNameLabel.frame.height